# Transfer data from msi installer to the installed exe

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-installer

I am trying to preform silent install to a windows servies via msi file and i want to transfer data at the installation to some config file(text file) that serve the exe windows service that the msi install.

The silent install command that i am executing is :

```
msiexec /u Installer.msi /q
```

When the msi installation is finish i call (automatically) to the "after install" event of the project installer and i want to build a txt file with few configuration for the windows service, one of the configuration parameters need to be inserted at the msi like ip address for some server.

Hope you get the idea and what i am struggling with..

Comment: This is a big topic. There are many answers that touch on this. First of all we need to determine what tool to use to create the installer?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2017 ,i learned how to make an installer and msi to windows service with the tutorial on YouTube [Installer + msi 2 part video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwTYYPRcWj0)

Comment: @SteinÅsmul ant idea?